# Establishing connection to DB2 takes time when application is run as service

Tags: odbc, db2, jetty

Connecting to DB2 from my Scala-app on top of Jetty work fine (1-2 seconds) when I run the app in console,by starting jetty manually "java -jar start.jar". However, when I start Jetty as a service, the connection takes 30-60 seconds to establish.

This is something I have spent few days trying to solve.

First I thought it is something to do with the iSeries Access ODBC Driver, which is used. I have another app written with Javascript, running on top of Node.js, which seems to work ok with this connection. I also played with most of the options this driver provides, but they didn't seem to help. Then I thought the problem has to be with th JDBC, and I tried to use com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc, but this didn't seem to fix the problem.

I put a logger to inspect what happens with the connection, but this didn't bring any extra help. Both connections seems similar, except when run as service it takes at least ten times longer to establish connection.

I thought that the issue could be if DB2-driver tries to authenticate against Activer directory, which is in use, so I created a local user "foobar". I set the iSeries to use this user ID as default. This didn't help either. I also tried to run the service with my username, which didn't help.

I'm currently out of ideas. Is it possible that starting Jetty manually on console loads different settings than by starting it as a service (net start app).

Any help would be much appreciated!

Stack:

- DB2 on external server. No access to configure.
- iSeries Access ODBC Driver, version 9.00.00.00
- Scala app, Scalatra framework
- Jetty 8.1.3 container
- NSSM to wrap Jetty as a service. Uses java.exe (copied to app-directory) and the options are "-jar start.jar".
- Windows 2003 server

Connection is setup simply with DriverManager:

```
private def foobarDbConnection: Connection = {
  Class.forName(Settings.foobarDbDriver)
  DriverManager.getConnection(Settings.foobarDatabase, 
                              Settings.foobarUsername, 
                              Settings.foobarPassword)
}
```

Settings:

```
def foobarDbDriver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Jcc"
def foobarDatabase = "jdbc:odbc:FOOBAR"
def foobarUsername = "foo"
def foobarPassword = "bar"
```

Here's log from connection:

```
13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:FOOBAR")

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO:     trying driver[className=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver,com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver@f6e15e]

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO:     trying driver[className=sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver,sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver@e8fdc9]

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: *Driver.connect (jdbc:odbc:FOOBAR)

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: JDBC to ODBC Bridge: Checking security

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: No SecurityManager present, assuming trusted application/applet

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: Allocating Environment handle (SQLAllocEnv)

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: hEnv=92738208

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: Allocating Connection handle (SQLAllocConnect)

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: hDbc=92739360

13.2.2013 13:45:54 com.foo.lib.DbConnectionFactory$JDBCLogWriter write
INFO: Connecting (SQLDriverConnect), hDbc=92739360, szConnStrIn=DSN=FOOBAR;UID=foo;PWD=bar
```

Comment: Gut feeling is that it's either a DNS issue, or a JVM difference (either different JVMs or different configurations)

Comment: Generic instructions to get more information: 1) Enable tracing in the drivers. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0506fechner/ for that. 2) Take a look at the DB2's db2diag.log when your problem occurs. 3) Generate ODBC trace as well: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274551 4) Forcing thread dump of the JVM when it is waiting for the mentioned 30-60 seconds will give you an idea what component might be causing the problems... On *nix you would just kill -3 <pid>, no idea about Windows..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few days of tracing and using Wireshark I managed to solve this by adding a local user into Windows server. In this case the name of the local user didn't matter (didn't have to be same as the username used in the DB2-connection). If the local user belonged into Administrator -group, then the problem persisted, so I created the local user without this group. It sounds like only the users on domain, or on admin-group are checked by active directory.